# Should a HTML table with checkboxes to select each row be contained in a fieldset with a legend element?

Tags: html, accessibility

Fieldset and legend elements are used to group related form controls. This is easy to understand and apply for "regular" forms, e.g. a "Your Details" fieldset with text input fields for first name, surname etc.

However, should fieldset and legend elements be used on a list page in an application, where users select table rows with associated checkboxes, prior to performing a bulk action on the selected rows?

For example:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Users</legend>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectedItem" value="Anna" /></td>
          <td>Anna</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelectedItem" value="Chris" /></td>
          <td>Chris</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <label for="ListAction">Bulk action</label>
    <select id="ListAction" name="ListAction">
      <option value="Nothing" selected="selected">Select action</option>
      <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
      <option value="Suspend">Suspend</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="BulkActionGo" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H71.html states that "Grouping controls is most important for related radio buttons and checkboxes. A set of radio buttons or checkboxes is related when they all submit values for a single named field."

This is the case in the example above, but fieldset/legend still doesn't seem like a natural fit for this use case, which may contain a lot of tabular data - and unrelated pagination controls - rather than a simple set of form controls.

Comment: yes, anything can be in a `fieldset`, it's like a general container for forms

Comment: Normally, the `submit` shouldn't be in the `<fieldset>`, however.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Good point, and in this case it'd require positioning hacks to visually associate the submit button with its bulk action selector.

Comment: _Edit: as well as bulk action controls, there are numeric input fields with "Go" buttons for jumping directly to a specific page of tabular data._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to name each checkbox with a different name, for instance using an array (which is easily parsable in PHP for instance)

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelItem[0]" value="Anna" title="Select Anna" /></td>
   <td>Anna</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="SelItem[1]" value="Chris" title="Select Chris" /></td>
   <td>Chris</td>
 </tr>
```

This way it will be apparent for assistive technologies (and any inner algorithm inside your software or external softwares) that **your intent is not to create group related checkboxes, but a set of checkboxes related to individual records.**

The `fieldset` is useful for situations where the legend give the instructions:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select your favorite Beatles</legent>
  <label><input type="checkbox" nama="fab4" value="John" />John</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" nama="fab4" value="Paul" />Paul</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" nama="fab4" value="George" />George</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" nama="fab4" value="Ringo" />Ringo</label>
</fieldset>
```

If you want to specify characteristics about individual records, the intent is different and the checkbox names may be linked to the row, not to the column.

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="member">
    <div class="name">John</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="john[is_singer]" value="1" />Sing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="john[play_guitar]" value="1" />Play guitar</label>
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    <div class="name">Paul</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="paul[is_singer]" value="1" />Sing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="paul[play_guitar]" value="1" />Play guitar</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will let assistive technologies handle the form easily without the use of any redundant `fieldset`

Answer (score -2):

No, there's no reason to include it in a fieldset. If you want to apply styling elements or refer to it in JavaScript, you can put it in a div, but a fieldset doesn't have any practical application in this case.

Comment: fieldsets are for wrapping form control elements, and they always have a practical application in forms. or rather, this is what they are for.

Comment: A `<fieldset>` should always be used, instead of non-descript containers like `<div>` because a `<fieldset>` has semantic meaning, while a `<div>` doesn't. The advice above is horribly bad, for both accessibility and semantics.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question, yes a fieldset is appropriate

Comment: Feel free to delete your answer and recover your reputation.